# Search exact phrase by multiple fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have products with attributes. For example "name", "brand", "color", "category", "size". When I'm searching products by phrase (for example "black jacket puma"), besides exact match with "brand" = "puma", "color" = "black", "category" = "jacket" or "name" = "Black puma jacket", I have also products with a partial match. My query is:

```
'match'    => [
    'message'   => [
        'query'     => "black puma jacket"
        'operator'  => 'and'
    ]
]
```

I also tried this query:

```
'multi_match'   => [
    'fields'    => [
        'brand',
        'color',
        'name'
    ],
    'query' => 'puma black jacket',
]
```

What's wrong with my query?

UPD:

My mappings:

```
'brand' => [
    'type'      => 'string',
    'fields'    => [
        'keyword'   => [
            'type'              => 'string',
            'analyzer'          => 'slug',
            'index_options'     => 'docs',
        ],
        'raw'   => [
            'type'      => 'string',
            'analyzer'  => 'format',
        ]
    ]
],
'color' => [
    'type'  => 'string',
    'fields'    => [
        'keyword'   => [
            'type'              => 'string',
            'analyzer'          => 'slug',
            'index_options'     => 'docs',
        ],
        'raw'   => [
            'type'      => 'string',
            'analyzer'  => 'format',
        ]
    ]
],
'category' => [
    'type'  => 'string',
    'fields'    => [
        'keyword'   => [
            'type'              => 'string',
            'analyzer'          => 'slug',
            'index_options'     => 'docs',
        ],
        'raw'   => [
            'type'      => 'string',
            'analyzer'  => 'format',
        ]
    ]
],
'category_id' => [
    'type'  => 'integer',
],
'store_id' => [
    'type'  => 'integer',
],
'size' => [
    'type'  => 'string',
    'fields'    => [
        'keyword'   => [
            'type'              => 'string',
            'analyzer'          => 'slug',
            'index_options'     => 'docs',
        ],
        'raw'   => [
            'type'      => 'string',
            'analyzer'  => 'format',
        ]
    ]
],
'material' => [
    'type'  => 'string',
    'fields'    => [
        'keyword'   => [
            'type'              => 'string',
            'analyzer'          => 'slug',
            'index_options'     => 'docs',
        ],
        'raw'   => [
            'type'      => 'string',
            'analyzer'  => 'format',
        ]
    ]
],
'type' => [
    'type'  => 'string',
    'fields'    => [
        'keyword'   => [
            'type'              => 'string',
            'analyzer'          => 'slug',
            'index_options'     => 'docs',
        ],
        'raw'   => [
            'type'      => 'string',
            'analyzer'  => 'format',
        ]
    ]
],
'volume' => [
    'type'  => 'string',
    'fields'    => [
        'keyword'   => [
            'type'              => 'string',
            'analyzer'          => 'slug',
            'index_options'     => 'docs',
        ],
        'raw'   => [
            'type'      => 'string',
            'analyzer'  => 'format',
        ]
    ]
],
'price' => [
    'type'  => 'float',
],
'desc' => [
    'type'  => 'string',
],
'sku' => [
    'type'  => 'string',
    'index' => 'not_analyzed'
],
'picture' => [
    'type'  => 'string',
    'index' => 'not_analyzed'
]
```

];

Comment: try query: {
    bool : {
        must: {
            match: { text: 'black puma jacket'} 
        }
    }
}

Comment: try query: {
    bool : {
        must: {
            match: { text: 'black puma jacket'} 
        }
    }
}

Comment: nope. this query returns an empty result

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are trying to achieve and details abut your mappings. thanks

Comment: @AssaelAzran, I placed my mappings. My goal is to search only items, where attributes or name matched my query string. If I searching "black jacket", I want to see only items where "black" and "jacket" exists (no matter where - product properties or name) and pass items with "black" or "jacket" match only. If I have in DB 10 item with a color "Black" and 5 items with a type or category "Jacket" and only 2 items with a color "Black" and type "Jacket", search result must contain only 2 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your mappings and requirements i think [cross_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields) might help you.

Example with only 2 properties (color and category):

Post a few documents:

```
POST my_index/_doc/1
{    
    "color": "black",
    "category": "1"
}

POST my_index/_doc/2
{    
    "color": "black",
    "category": "2"
}

POST my_index/_doc/3
{    
    "color": "black",
    "category": "3"
}

POST my_index/_doc/4
{   
    "color": "1",
    "category": "jacket"
}

POST my_index/_doc/5
{   
    "color": "2",
    "category": "jacket"
}

POST my_index/_doc/6
{   
    "color": "3",
    "category": "jacket"
}

POST my_index/_doc/6
{   
    "color": "3",
    "category": "jacket"
}

POST my_index/_doc/7
{   
    "color": "black",
    "category": "jacket"
}

POST my_index/_doc/8
{   
    "color": "black",
    "category": "jacket"
}
```

Your search query will look like:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "black jacket",
      "fields": [],
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "operator": "and",
      "analyzer": "standard"
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
{
 "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.2192403,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "7",
        "_score" : 1.2192403,
        "_source" : {
          "color" : "black",
          "category" : "jacket"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "8",
        "_score" : 1.2192403,
        "_source" : {
          "color" : "black",
          "category" : "jacket"
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see we didn't get all other document with partial match of **black** or **jacket**

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, your example working as I want. One more question - "fields" param in "multi_match" can't be empty? Your example worked for me only if I set exact fields list.

Comment: What is your elasticsearch version?

Comment: "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.1",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-04-04T12:25:05Z",
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
}

Comment: According to documentation **If no fields are provided, the multi_match query defaults to the index.query.default_field index settings, which in turn defaults to all fields** this is relevant for 7.4 . in 2.3 this documentation does not exists so i think it's not supported. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html , https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html

Comment: Got it. Anyway, your example working as I want and set fields list isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, I would group brand, color & category into one field and then apply phrase match. You need to modify products mapping

```
PUT /products
{
  "mappings":{
    "properties":{
      "brand": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "name",
        ...
      },
      "color": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "name",
        ...
      },
      "category": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "name",
        ...
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Search using phrase match on name field

```
GET /products/_search
{
  "query":{
    "match_phrase": {
      "name": {
        "query": {
          "name": "black puma jacket",
          "slop": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```